# Is there a way to easily change my hamburger menu icon back to three lines on the closeNav function?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a hamburger menu that opens and closes when the menu icon is clicked on. When I first open the nav, the background colour is adjusted to a width of 100%, and the three lines transition/change to an "X". However, when I click on the "X" again to close the nav, the background width changes to 0%, but the icon does not change.

I am trying to use JavaScript to do this as well. Although I am not sure what is the simplest way to achieve a hamburger menu function.

Currently I have tried to use the onclick function and x.classList.toggle("change"); to change the menu icon.

HTML

```
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav(this)"></a>

</div>

  <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav(this)">
 <div class="line1"></div>
<div class="line2"></div>
  <div class="line3"></div>
</span>
```

CSS

```
 body {
font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidenav {
height: 100%;
width: 0;
position: fixed;
z-index: 1;
top: 0;
left: 0;
 background-color: #111;
overflow-x: hidden;
transition: 0.5s;
 padding-top: 60px;
opacity:0.6;
}

.sidenav a {
 padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 25px;
color: #818181;
 display: block;
 }

.sidenav a:hover {
 color: #f1f1f1;
 }

 .line1, .line2, .line3{
  width:35px;
 height:2px;
 background-color:black;
 margin:6px 0;
 transition:0.3s;
 }


 .change .line1 {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease;
  }

.change .line2 {opacity: 0;}

 .change .line3 {
   -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-7px, -2px);
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease;

 }

   @media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
   function openNav(x) {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "100%";
  x.classList.toggle("change");

  }


 function closeNav() {
 document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
 x.classList.toggle("change");
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yor error that you add class to burger and remove class from `#mySidenav > a`

In next example I show how its can work.

HTML:

```
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" style="background:red" onclick="closeNav()"></a>
</div>
<span id="burger" style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">
  <div class="line1"></div>
  <div class="line2"></div>
  <div class="line3"></div>
</span>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function openNav() {
    mySidenav.style.width = "100%";
    burger.classList.add("change");
}

function closeNav() {
    mySidenav.style.width = "0";
    burger.classList.remove("change");
}

// mySidenav == document.getElementById("mySidenav")
// burger == document.getElementById("burger ")
```

[Codepen example](https://codepen.io/dev1ldragon/pen/jOOyodY)

Comment: Thank you. Would you possibly know why the X is now missing when I change the background colour. Or rather it gets hidden. I added the codepen example.

Comment: X disappears because you have it in the previous position of the layer.

Comment: I noticed in your Codepen that to close the hamburger menu, you need to click on the padded area for the sidenav. Is there another way to to this? Rather than creating a block around it?

Comment: https://codepen.io/dev1ldragon/pen/jOOyodY - work on click in hamburger

Comment: But its not good ideia doint that others have done. You can find aolot of examples in google that can feet your prerequisits. for example if you vant to do somethins simple you can check: [70 hamburger examples](https://www.digitaldesignjournal.com/best-hamburger-menu-css/), or if you want do something big you need to use js/css component framework